# Can I use a query string in a Silveright relative URI? If so, how? If not, why not?

Tags: silverlight, query-string, relative-url

I have a Silverlight app where I'm trying to load an image from the server via a relative URL that includes a query string.  Specifically, I'm accessing a proxy page called proxy.jsp that takes a parameter "url".  I've verified that the string I'm passing to the System.Uri constructor has the query string, but it would appear that Silverlight is stripping or ignoring it.  Here's some sample code:

```
string proxyUrl = "../proxy.jsp?url=anything";
Uri uri = new Uri(proxyUrl, UriKind.Relative);
BitmapImage im = new BitmapImage(uri);
someSilverlightImage.Source = im;
```

I know that I have the base URL correct, because my proxy.jsp is returning the default image it returns if the url parameter is null.  For fun, I tried displaying the property uri.Query with a MessageBox and got an exception saying that the Query property is only supported for UriKind.Absolute.  *But*, if I display `uri.ToString()`, I get the full URL I passed in.

My questions are:

1. Is my conclusion correct that, by default, Silverlight ignores the query string when making requests for relative URI's?
2. If so, is there any configuration I can do to override the default?
3. If I can't override the default, any insight into the design or implementation concerns that would have motivated this seemingly glaring omission?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't see why Silverlight would string the query string (that would be crazy).  Maybe you need to URL-encode the URL (ie, `HttpUtility.UrlEncode("anything")` in your example).

Comment: I'm URL-encoding the various parameter values during construction of the url string.  Weirdest thing is, I display the exact URL passed to the Uri constructor in my app for debugging purposes.  I can copy it, paste it into my browser (prepending the appropriate server info), and get the image I'm expecting.  I agree it sounds crazy, and I do hope I'm just making some dome mistake somewhere, but I'm pretty stumped so far.

Comment: Oh, wait.  I'm encoding the parameters that are part of the target URL to construct the "url" parameter, but I'm not encoding that whole thing to escape it to become a parameter itself.  I'll try that.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it appears that the Uri constructor does that automatically.  The string I print out for debug purposes has the slashes converts http:// to http%3a%2f%2f.  I can further confirm that this seems to be specific to relative URLs.  I just switched my JSP page to return absolute URLs instead, and now everything works.